# Find the lowest common divisor in divisors array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a math question in javascript:

I have array of divisors :

var divisors  = ["3","4","5","10","12","15","20","30","60"]

and number of items that should be divide without a reminder in one of those items:

var items_to_divide = ["10","30"]

i'm looking for a function that will give me the lowest common divisors from list of divisors (var divisors) between in items_to_divide.

In this example the result should be 5, cause 10 / 5 = 2 and 30 / 5 = 6 so 5 is the lowest common divider, cause they both divide with 5 without a reminder.

anyone can suggest a nice logic here?

Comment: Why not just check for their lowest common denominator and then look for it in the list?

Comment: @EvanKnowles that can work can you post an example?

Comment: One gotcha to watch out for - your arrays contain Strings, not Numbers. `parseInt` will be needed

Comment: @Joe yes this is true they contain strings.

Comment: Well, in your case, 10 % 10 = 0 and 30 % 10 = 0. So the correct answer is 10! Isn't it?

Comment: @fish_ball but i'm looking for the common divider that will divide it without a reminder, it this case 5 will divide them both without leaving any reminder cause 10 / 5 = 2 and 30 / 5 = 6 so 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following steps :

1. Sort your divisor array ascending
2. Loop on this array
3. Check if the current divisor divides all items to divide
4. if yes, this is the lowest common divider.

An implementation of this algorithm could be this one :

```
function best_divisor() {
  var division;

  // Sort divisor array from lowest value to highest one
  divisors = divisors.sort(function(a,b) {return +a > +b;});

  // Test each value of this array
  for (var i=0; i<divisors.length; i++) {
    divide = true;

    // check if it divides all values from the items_to_divide
    for (var j=0; j<items_to_divide.length; j++) {
      division = items_to_divide[j] / divisors[i];
      if(division !== Math.round(division)) {
        divide = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    // If all divisions give integers, this divisor is the lowest one
    if(divide) return divisors[i];
  }

  // No divisor found
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Just a very minor nitpick - if you pass an empty array of `items_to_divide` this will return the first `divisor`. It's probably better to use a solution that's falsey as standard, and only returns truthy on passing all the tests. Also, `divide` is not needed - just use `undefined === division` as your test and you save a variable

Comment: @Joe : it depends on the requirement, but if this array is empty, the lowest common divisor is the lowest integer in the `divisors` array... So it works too...

Answer (score 1):

```
var answer = NaN;
for(var i = 0; i < divisors.length; ++i) {
    var ok = true;
    for(var j = 0; j < items_to_divide.length; ++j) {
        if(parseInt(items_to_divide) % parseInt(divisors[i]) != 0) {
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    answer = answer && Math.min(ans || parseInt(divisors[i]), parseInt(divisors[i]));
}

console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will make sure it does not continue to search for divisors once it has found the lowest.

```
var divisors = [3, 4, 5, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60];
var items_to_divide = [10, 30];
var divisor = false;
for (var i = 0; i < divisors.length; i++) {
    var divisorfound = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < items_to_divide.length; j++) {
        if (items_to_divide[j] % divisors[i] !== 0) {
            divisorfound = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (divisorfound === true) {
        divisor = divisors[i];
        break;
    }
}
console.log(divisor);
```